# How to pass $_GET in pagination in php

Tags: php, pagination

This code works perfectly if i am just running the pagination, but when there is a `$_GET` variable passed it shows the first page properly and when clicked on next it loads all the data in the db and runs from beginning.

I would like to know how can i pass a `$_GET` variable passed.

```
<?php     
if ($currentpageRec > 1) {
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpageRec=1'>First Page</a> ";
    prevpageRec = $currentpageRec - 1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpageRec=$prevpageRec'>Previous Page</a> ";
}

for ($x = ($currentpageRec - $rangeRec); $x < (($currentpageRec + $rangeRec) + 1); $x++) {
    if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpagesRec)) {
        if ($x == $currentpageRec) {
            echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
        } else {
            echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpageRec=$x'>$x</a> ";
        }
    } 
} 

if ($currentpageRec != $totalpagesRec) {
    $nextpageRec = $currentpageRec + 1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpageRec=$nextpageRec'>Next Page</a> ";
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpageRec=$totalpagesRec'>Last Page</a> ";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post the actual database query you use to fetch the data to paginate over.

Comment: Also what does this `$_GET` rec contain and what do you want to happen when the code see this `$_GET` rec

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, I am wondering whether you should register global variables
http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Your code could use the variables as globals, whereas in fact it should refer to the GET variables, e.g.

```
<?php     
    if ($_GET['currentpageRec'] > 1) {
    //[etc]
?>
```

Further to the comment below: I tried to say: user $_GET (etcetera), as the code appears to be based on the (depreciated) global variabels.

--- edit ---

Further to the updated shared code: you have to pass each variable again when using the pagination, e.g. for your last line

```
<?
// code to define $totalpagesRec
// code to define $KeyWord
// personal preference to split the echo between static texts and variables
echo " <a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?currentpageRec=".$totalpagesRec."&keyword=".$KeyWord."'>Last Page</a> ";
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: **Warning** This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. **And we are now on PHP7**

Comment: Ok I removed my DV